# How to send Outlook emails from a shared mailbox using Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

The below code sends emails from my Excel file.

However I do not know where to add the `.sentonbehalfof` line to send from a specific shared mailbox that I have permission to send from.

```vb
Sub send_email()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Statements")
    
    Dim OA As Object
    Dim msg As Object
    
    Set OA = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Dim each_row As Integer
    Dim last_row As Integer
    last_row = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(sh.Range("A:A"))
  
    For each_row = 2 To last_row
        Set msg = OA.createitem(0)
        msg.To = sh.Range("A" & each_row).Value
        first_name = sh.Range("B" & each_row).Value
        last_name = sh.Range("C" & each_row).Value
        msg.cc = sh.Range("D" & each_row).Value
        msg.Subject = sh.Range("E" & each_row).Value
        msg.body = sh.Range("F" & each_row).Value
        date_to_send = sh.Range("H" & each_row).Value
        date_to_send = Format(date_to_send, "dd/mm/yyyy")
        Status = sh.Range("I" & each_row).Value
        current_date = Format(Date, "dd/mm/yyyy")
        If date_to_send = current_date Then
            If sh.Range("G" & each_row).Value <> "" Then
                msg.attachments.Add sh.Range("G" & each_row).Value
                Cells(each_row, 9).Value = "Sent"
                Content = Replace(msg.body, "<>", first_name + " " + last_name)
                msg.body = Content
                msg.send
            Else
                Cells(each_row, 9).Value = "Sent"
                Content = Replace(msg.body, "<>", first_name + " " + last_name)
                msg.body = Content
                msg.send
            End If
        End If
    Next each_row
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding

```
 msg.SentOnBehalfOfName = "Your shared email address"
```

above this line

```
 msg.cc = sh.Range("D" & each_row).Value
```

It worked for me!